# Jhipster and Spring Security - Add Authentication provider leaving active default jdbcauthentication mode

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap, jhipster

I've added a custom LDAP authentication provider mechanism to my jHipster application. Without insert any `configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` or `configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method to `SecurityConfiguration` class, but with `@Component` annotation on my custom `AuthenticationProvider` implementation, the new authentication work fine, but, I lose the default authentication with users on database.

I try to add this on `securityConfiguration`:

```
@Inject
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    super.configure(auth);
    auth.authenticationProvider(aDauthenticationProvider);
}
```

but the result is the same, I lose the database authentication.

How could I add the default auth mechanism to the list of providers of AuthenticationManagerBuilder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, I write this if someone have my same issue.

It's sufficient to add this code line on GlobalConfigure method:

```
auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
```

to add the predefined JDBC authentication method to the list of authentication providers.